# firebase dynamic link with react-navigation

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

I have followed this document https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.1.x/links/android and able to run `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://abc123.app.goo.gl" com.myapp.superapp` to start the app.

How can open a dynamic link `https://abc123.app.goo.gl` it open the `VideoScreen` and pass the `contentparam`

```
Video:{
  screen : VideoScreen,
  path:'wvc/:contentparam',
}
```

**So I tried this when clicking https://abc123.app.goo.gl (dynamic link):**

```
componentDidMount () {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
    }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

However app opened but `console.log` given `null`

Comment: are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: @bennygenel yes, but `react-navigation` deep linking not able to open in browser

Comment: if you want to use `path` property from `react-navigation` you need to combine links from firebase and deep linking from react-navigation. Another approach would be listening to [link events](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#addeventlistener) an manually navigating user.

Comment: did you mean `Linking.getInitialURL()` for the `https://abc123.app.goo.gl` , if the link is dynamic link then do somethings?

Comment: @bennygenel hi, I try your suggestion `Linking` , question updated

Comment: Did toy fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason `firebase.links().onLink((url)` does not work in RNFB v6. 
Here is a comment on this bug from one of RNFB maintainers 
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3008

Use should use react native `Link` instead, as a temporary workaround: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/linking

Here is an example you can use:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL()
      .then(url => {
        if (url) {
          console.log('Initial url is: ' + group);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to listen to firebase links

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const unsubscribe = firebase.links().onLink((url) => {
    console.log('dynamic links', url)
    // do navigate with url above
    // you have to handle your self
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  unsubscribe()
}
```

docs: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/links/reference/links#onLink